# what is meant by "Apply all migrations: admin, auth, authentication, contenttypes, sessions, sites" in Django Python 2.2 migrate command?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-migrations

[image: **enter image description here**]

I am trying to migrate all the models in my Django project to a database, after migration, There are many tables missing in the database, but when I run `python manage.py migrate` there is no migration to apply, and what is this Operations to perform, and what exactly mean by **Apply all migrations: adming, auth, authentication, contenttypes, sessions, sites** ?

Comment: "Apply all migrations" is just an information for which apps the migrations would be run (see [django-code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py#L176)). Please show which tables you have, which you would expect and what you have in your INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Have you ran 'python manage.py makemigrations' before running 'python manage.py migrate'.

Comment: Yes, I did and got `no changes detected`.